# CAML output remove time from DateTime

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, caml

I am creating a blog roll using a Sharepoint Online list, and I would like the DateTime to display with only month, day and year, and not time or day of the week. (currently producing "Wed Jul 11 2018 16:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)")

My current Code is:

```js
$(function () {
 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
 
});
 
function retrieveListItems() {
 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('News Archives');
 
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    camlQuery.set_viewXml(

    '<View><Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name="Publication_x0020_Date"  /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today /></Value></Lq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Publication_x0020_Date" Ascending="False"/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>20</RowLimit></View>'
     
    );
 
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
 
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
 
    );
 
}
 
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
 
    var listItemInfo = '';
 
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    
    
    
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
         
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();        
         
        listItemInfo += 
        '<div class="newsitem">' +

        '<h1 class="news-title"><a href="' + oListItem.get_item('Title0').get_url() + '">' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '</a></h1>' +
        
        '<p>' + oListItem.get_item('Author0') +  ', ' + oListItem.get_item('Publication_x0020_Date') + '</p>' +

         oListItem.get_item('Summary_x0020__x002b__x0020_Medi') + 
                 
        '</div>';
        
 
    }
    
    
 
    $("#newsfeed").html(listItemInfo);
 
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
 
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
 
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 
}
```

I am hoping to adjust this section

```js
oListItem.get_item('Publication_x0020_Date')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MicrosoftAjax.js to format the datetime field, sample script.

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
        });

        function retrieveListItems() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('News Archives');
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
            );
        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var listItemInfo = '';
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var publicationDate = oListItem.get_item('Publication_x0020_Date');
                var formatDate = publicationDate.format('MMM/dd/yyyy');
                alert(formatDate);
            }            
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!